# Как починить импорт проектов C# в VS Code?

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild

При попытке открыть любую папку содержащую проект на dotnet 6 VS Code выдает следующую ошибку в Output, даже не сам VS Code сколько OmniSharp:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте майкрософта было описано решение в виде global.json, с указанием версии dotnet которая появляется при вводе в терминал `dotnet --list-sdks`, но проблема в том что это ничего не меняет, если у кого-то не загружается скриншот - вот текст основной ошибки:

`/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1232,5): Error: The reference assemblies for ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found. You might be using an older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio and/or your .NET SDK.`

Кто может подсказать как это решать?

Comment: .NET Framework имеет последнюю версию 4.8. Он не может быть шестой версии. Покажите, как именно задаётся версия дотнета.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я не знаю как она задается, я знаю только что в системе установлен 6 дотнет, и что я создаю проект командой `dotnet new console -n "Test"` и после того как открываю папку проекта в вскод - вот такая вот ошибка